# jQuery fullcalendar: prev-next events not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using **jquery fullcalendar**, the problem that come across is:

How to write actions for **prev** and **next** events...
i had tried this:

```
$('.fc-button-prev span').click(function(){
   alert('preview');
});
```

but it won't goes into the function all time, sometimes only it showing the alert... what is the problem behind it..? Is there any other method to call prev and next month function in **jquery fullcalendar**

please refer it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5XNT7/2/

Comment: provide jsfiddle please When using external JS file like fullcalender,so it would be easy to solve ur problem

Comment: what is `jquery fullcalendar`..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ,its JQuery plugin

Comment: refer http://jsfiddle.net/5XNT7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Since these buttons are created dynamically, you should use event delegate for that,

```
$(document).on("click",".fc-button-prev span",function(){

});
```

Comment: thank's anoop for your answer, but unfortunately it won't works

Comment: can you try with this $(document).on("click",".fc-button-prev",function(){

Comment: @rbvishnu machane, that fiddle doesnt have anything useful. Can you refer the script for full calender in that fiddle?.,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56510/discussion-between-rb-vishnu-and-anoop-joshi).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/prev/)

If `$('.fc-button-prev span')` is the element to navigate to prev month, this should work

```
$('.fc-button-prev span').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
});
```

Comment: yes, but while clinking the next button, it wont enter into the function all time..... that is my problem